# Getting common ID from two DataTables

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two `DataTable`s : `dt1` & `dt2`. `dt1` contains one field, `ID` and `dt2` contains two fields, `ass_ID` and `Name`.

I have to get the number of matched `ID`s from these two `DataTable`s. How do I do this? Any easy way to compare them or anything to get the count of matched `ID`s (common `ID`s) in both of these tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var count = (from dr1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
            from dr2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
            where dr1.Field<int>("ID") == dr2.Field<int>("ass_ID")
            select dr1).Count();
```

Or

```
var count = (from dr1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
             join j in dt2.AsEnumerable() on dr1.Field<int>("ID") equals j.Field<int>("ass_ID")
             select j).Count();
```

Comment: Thanks Habib :). the work is done. can u briefly tell me what it, when you write dt1.AsNumerable() ?

Comment: Its `AsEnumerable` which is an extension method, and let you Use LINQ on data tables. You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string strExpression = string.Format("ID = '{0}'",dt2.Columns["ass_ID"]);
DafaultView dv = new DefaultView();
dv = dt1.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = strExpression;
//work with dv (DefaultView)
```